# Reading a h5 file in C# with the correct values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to read a h5 file for my Unity project and read the data from the file and use it in Unity. I opened the file first hith Python and h5py and the file contains of multiple arrays and data like this:

[image]

Now when I am trying to read the file in C# (Unity) I am getting this value for a single entry:

[image]

Has someone any recommendations (or sample code) on  how to read the file properly so that the values match these from the h5py output. My guess is that the datatypes arent the same because an int in C# is presented as 32bit but I only need 16 Bits. I tried to convert the number in UInt16 but I got an outofrange exception. I used HDFPinvoke and other libraries but I couldnt fix the error.Couldnt I just directly use the Python Script with IronPython to get the data in runtime ?

Comment: Would you mind to post the array's number of dimensions and their sizes?

Comment: the dimension is 2d and the size/length are 17189 and 19 so there are 17189 arrays in the set and each of them has 19 entrys. The first size number could vary I currently not home but from my memory it should be this size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with HDFPinvoke and friends but you could try [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) to read an HDF5 dataset in C#. Based on the info provided, the reading could be done as follows:

```
ushort[,] values = new ushort[17189, 19];

HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM myDataset INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableRegister(values));

for(int i = 0; i < 17189; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 19; j++)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(values[i, j]);
    }
}
```

For additional information, see HDFql reference manual [here](https://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) and examples on how to use it in C# [here](https://www.hdfql.com/examples).

Comment: I read the documentation briefly and tried opening and reading my file and I wanted to get only one value first @SOG with this code:                                                                                            `string filePath = "C:\\Users\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\WebXR\\Assets\\LineChart\\converted.h5"; HDFql.Execute("USE FILE " +filePath); ushort[,]values = new ushort[170761,19]; HDFql.Execute("SELECT data INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableRegister(values)); Debug.Log("ONE DATA ENTRY: "+values[2300,4]);`  but I am getting 0 as return, do you know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: And sorry for the format of the code STack Overflow didnt let me make it format in code

Comment: I believe you need to surround the name of the dataset with double-quote for it to work properly since `DATA` is a reserved keyword in HDFql. That is why the value printed is `0` since the dataset is never read and the variable populated with values. In other words, for it to work properly do the following: `HDFql.Execute("SELECT \"data\" INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableRegister(values));`. After making this change, HDFql should be able to read the dataset which will then make the value to be printed correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working when I try it  here m code     `ushort[,]values = new ushort[170761,19];
     //HDFql.Execute("USE FILE " + h5File);
     HDFql.Execute("USE FILE converted.h5");
     HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM \"data\" INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableRegister(values));
     Debug.Log("ONE DATA ENTRY:  "+values[2300,4]);` Do you maybe have another example? These on the provided site didn't really helped me neither

Comment: What is the value returned by the `Execute` method?

Comment: for the first one its -3 and the second -5

Comment: If you see HDFql reference manual section 5.1 (https://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) `-3` refers to error not found (`HDFQL_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`) - it seems that HDFql can't find file `converted.h5`. The `-5` refers to error not open (`HDFQL_ERROR_NOT_OPEN`) which makes sense since you are trying to read a dataset and no file is opened.

Comment: Thanks now I got the problem but I tried every way possible to include the data, it is in the same directory, I also tried it with giving the whole path or include the data with Unity but it wouldnt work is there any other way to include the data in „USE FILE“ ?

Comment: When you do `HDFql.Execute("USE FILE converted.h5");` what value is returned?

Comment: the value -3 is being returned so the file can not be found but it wont work even when I try to enter the whole path of the file

Comment: Do you mind to open the file with the absolute (whole) path surrounded with double-quote and see if the issue goes away?

Comment: no unfortunately it didnt maybe my file is not suited for HDFql , although I can open it with Python

Comment: Would you mind to share the file? Maybe I could give it a go and see if I can find the issue (if any).

Comment: Here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d8512a9778ffaea38549b364eaf9ab6520220605214843/411712

Comment: Thanks - I can successfully open the file using HDFqlCLI (a command-line interface tool shipped with HDFql) and read dataset `data` in Linux. This means that it shouldn't be a problem to read it programmatically (using C# in this case). Let me check what is happening in Windows (it shouldn't be a problem though and I suspect it has something to do with the number of backslash specified in the whole path that is causing the issue you are seeing).

Comment: so what should I provide my whole code or the console output?

Comment: Are you sure that if you surround the whole path file with double-quote it still doesn't work? I tried at my side in Windows and it works perfectly. Could you please try the following and see how it goes: `HDFql.Execute("USE FILE \"C:\\Users\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\WebXR\\Assets\\LineChart\\converted.h5\"");`

Comment: Ok thanks now it works I tried it without using Unity and made a standalone C# project and it works fine there. Do you know why it wouldnt work in Unity?

Comment: Not sure why... right after executing the `Execute` method that gives the error, would you mind to do the following `System.Console.WriteLine(HDFql.ErrorGetMessage());` and post the output here?

Comment: Ok it is working know in Unity also I forgot a " . Thank you so much for your patience and your helpfulness